# How do I slow down the mouse cursor?

Tags: 12.04, mouse

I've been using Linux for over 10 years and just downloaded 12.04 to my wife's laptop. It looks good but I can't find a way to slow the cursor down (yes, I have gone to System Settings and they are as slow as possible). This is on a System 76 Pangolin laptop with the pad.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Since the site works best as a Q&A format, can you please post your question regarding mouse hover separately? Thanks!

Comment: Trackpad or mouse?

Comment: See <http://askubuntu.com/a/226173/28930>

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a separate wireless mouse try unplugging the usb dongle and plugging it back in.  That has worked for me.

Comment: If you are citing hardware failure, that may work, but this looks like software issues...