# How do I slow down my wireless mouse?

Tags: wireless, mouse

I set the pointer speed in System Setting as low as possible and it is still way too fast. It is a logitech M185 and I am running Ubuntu 12.04. I have the same mouse with my Mac Mini and it isn't crazy fast like the one on my Ubuntu computer.

Answer (score 4):

I just found the solution in [this external page](http://patrickmylund.com/blog/lowering-gaming-mouse-sensitivity-in-ubuntu-9-10/).

It seems that you have to modify the `Device Accel Constant Deceleration`. The original value is `1`, I tried a few settings and it seems that it works perfectly with `2.8` for me.

I used the following command, where `10` is the device id, so you should change the `10`
value with the corresponding for you:

```
xinput --set-prop 10 "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 2.8
```

How to know your `id` device? With this command you will see the list of your device and the `id`:

```
xinput --list --short
```

Comment: awesome but one issue is when the device reconnects it then resets that setting.

Answer (score 0):

As unlikely as it sounds, try unplugging the USB dongle and plugging it back end.
Sometimes this happens when it has hibernated then come back.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - http://www.hidpoint.com/hidpoint/overview/overview.html

It's a Linux version of Logitech's Setpoint software that can act as a configuration tool with various options, including sensitivity control.

Comment: Doesn't work with Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, what worked for me is:

```
xset m 32/10
```